# Отображение древовидной структуры в Symfony2 Form Entity Type

Tags: php, doctrine, form, symfony2

Имеется сущность, у которой реализовано дерево через указание родителя.

```
// ...
class Folder
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Folder")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;

    // ...
}
```

Форма сделана так:

```
$builder->add('parent', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Folder',
    ))
```

В таком случае список "Папок" получается "плоским", из простого максимум что можно сделать это описать в форм билдере query_builder и отсортировать по какому либо полю...

**Требуется**: вывести список "папок" в древовидном виде. например сейчас список всех папок будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
Folder4
```

а должен например так:

```
Folder1
  Folder4
    Folder3
  Folder2
```

т.е. будет тотже самый select option, но в особом порядке в соотвествии с иерархией parent-child, также внутри option добавлять пару пробелов для визуального отступа.

**Вторая задача более сложная**: было бы очень удобно скажем при редактировании Folder4 в списке пункт Folder3 отображать неактивным т.к. нельзя задать в качестве родителя своегоже детку :) ну и третий вопрос: как проверять этот же момент при сохранении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, задать логику вывода или не вывода значений дерева через Doctrine будет весьма сложно. Можно вынести в модель, получить подготовленные данные из нее и скормить их builder`у в качестве 3 параметра функции createForm(...). А что выводить или не выводить, это уже вы в модели сами определяете, исходя из логики приложения.

В контроллере

```
...
    $listEntity = $modelFolder->GetListForSelecet($data);
    $form = $this->createForm(new myType(), $entityFolder, array('listEntity' => $listEntity);
...
```

В классе формы myType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('idFolder', 'choice', 
            array('label' => 'Папка',
            'choices' => $options['listEntity'],
            'expanded' => false,
            'mapped' => false)
         );
}
```

еще в myType задать параметр listEntity = null, а то ругаться будет

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Folder',
        'listEntity' => null
    ));
}
```

Comment: задача давно решена, вот тут http://forum.sfhub.org/post/12418/#p12418 отписывался...